# how to load csv files in google colab for R?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

How to load CSV files in google colab for R?
For python, there are many answers but can someone guide how file can be imported in R for google colab.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "get a CSV file from my local system into the Colaboratory Environment" and not just importing it from inside the Colab file paths as per Korakot's suggestion, since your question wasn't very clear, I think you have two main options:

### 1. Upload a file directly through the shortcut in the side menu thingy.

[image: Side Menu]

Just click the icon there and upload your file to drive. Then, you can run normal r import functions by following the internal path like korakot put in this answer.

### 2. Connect your google drive

Assuming you're using a notebook [like the one created by Thong Nguyen](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BYnnbqeyZAlYnxR9IHC8tpW07EpDeyKR), you can use a python call to mount your own google drive, like this one:

```
cat(system('python3 -c "from google.colab import drive\ndrive.mount()"', intern=TRUE), sep='\n', wait=TRUE)
```

... which will initiate the login process to Google Drive and will allow you to access your files from google drive as if they were folders in colab. There's more info about this process [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/drive.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the read.csv function like

```
 data = read.csv('sample_data/mnist_test.csv')
```

It will look for the local files, but remember files uploaded here will be deleted when the instance is stopped.

[image: local files]

Comment: @JasonMatney I tested in Colab and it works. The path 'sample/mnist_test.csv' exists specifically in Colab.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use the Colab with R as runtime type (and Python code would not work therefore), you could also simply upload the file as MAIAkoVSky suggested in step 1 and then import it with

```
data <- read.csv('/content/your-file-name-here.csv')
```

The filepath can also be accessed by right clicking on the file in the interface.

Please be aware that the files will disappear once you disconnected from Colab. You would need to upload them again for the next session.